# Video frame rate is too slow from IP Camera using Aforge Jpegstream C#

Tags: c#-4.0, video-streaming, aforge, ip-camera

I'm using Aforge library to try to get a live stream from an IP Camera. My problem is, Frame rate is too slow and about one frame every 3 or 4 seconds! I have connected my camera directly to my computer through LAN port.

Here is my code :

```
JPEGStream stream;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        stream = new JPEGStream("http://192.168.1.88/pda.cgi?user=myusername&password=mypass&page=image&cam=1");
        stream.NewFrame += stream_NewFrame;

    }

    private void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {

        Bitmap bmp =(Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }

    private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stream.Start();
    }

    private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stream.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will count as an answer but, have you tried to edit the FrameInterval Property of the JPEGStream?.

Set that to 0 so you can get as many as frame as possible

```
stream.FrameInterval = 0;
```

But I'll suggest use the MJPEGStream instead of JPEGStream if your IP Cam is supporting it. It is faster than the JPEGStream